# Git merge master to branch and accept partial changes

Tags: git, merge

I am working on a feature branch which I wanted to keep up to date with the master update. I did git merge master to branch. This gave me lots of conflicts. I manually merged two conflicts and kept my changes on these two files. Now the rest of the files which are quite few, I want to accept the master changes. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do:

```
git checkout master -- file1 file2 file3 # get the files as they are on master branch (assuming the branch is master)
# then you could finish the merge
git merge --continue
```